# Spring Boot - Unable to acquire JDBC source after a few days

Tags: spring-boot, hikaricp

I have a Spring Boot 2.0 application. I have configured it with two datasources. The first is a database used by the application itself, the second datasource is used to pull in a product name from a Business Intelligence system.

I have configured Spring Boot, every minute to run a task, and this works fine for a couple of days, after which I see an error saying that

"HikariPool-1 - Connection is not available, request timed out after 30008ms"

If I restart the application, it starts working again.

I'm using Spring Data, and my datasource configuration looks like this;

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "defaultEntityManagerFactory",
        transactionManagerRef = "defaultTransactionManager",
        basePackages = {
                "com.domain.visualisation.shared.repository"
        }
)
public class DefaultDbConfig {

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "defaultDataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource")
    public DataSource defaultDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "defaultEntityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean
    entityManagerFactory(
            EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder,
            @Qualifier("defaultDataSource") DataSource dataSource
    ) {
        return builder
                .dataSource(dataSource)
                .packages("com.domain.visualisation.shared.entities")
                .persistenceUnit("default")
                .build();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "defaultTransactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager defaultTransactionManager(
            @Qualifier("defaultEntityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory defaultEntityManagerFactory
    ) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(defaultEntityManagerFactory);
    }
}
```

Here is an example of what one of the repositories look like;

```
public interface LineShiftRepository extends CrudRepository<LineShift, Long> {

/**
 * Delete all shifts items before a given date
 * @param date date to use as cut-off
 */
@Transactional
@Query("DELETE FROM LineShift ls WHERE ls.endDate < :date")
void deleteDataBeforeDate(@Param("date") Date date);

/**
 * Return the most recent shift before a given date
 * @param date a date and time
 * @return LineShift before date
 */
@Query(value = "SELECT TOP 1 * FROM line_shifts WHERE start_timestamp < :date ORDER BY end_timestamp DESC", nativeQuery = true)
public LineShift getLastShift(@Param("date") Date date);

/**
 * Returns a line shift for the line and date
 * @param line the line
 * @param date the date
 * @return a single LineShift
 */
@Query("SELECT ls FROM LineShift ls WHERE ls.line = :line AND ls.startDate <= :date AND ls.endDate > :date")
public LineShift getLineShiftByLineAndDate(@Param("line") Line line, @Param("date") Date date);
```

}

I can only suspect that maybe somewhere a connection isn't being released back to the pool, but I don't know where to start in terms of trying to find out where, and how to resolve it.

Application properties looks like this;

```
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect

spring.datasource.jdbc-url=jdbc:sqlserver://SPETUK-VSQL01;databaseName=ProductionMetrics
spring.datasource.username=user
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver

# Products
trwbi.datasource.jdbc-url=jdbc:sqlserver://Spetuk-RS02;databaseName=bi
trwbi.datasource.username=username
trwbi.datasource.password=password
trwbi.datasource.driverClassName=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
```

I managed to get a copy of the stack trace;

```
2019-02-25 10:20:01.398 ERROR 6264 --- [o-8080-exec-151] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection] with root cause

java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException: HikariPool-1 - Connection is not available, request timed out after 30000ms.
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createTimeoutException(HikariPool.java:669) ~[HikariCP-2.7.9.jar!/:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.getConnection(HikariPool.java:183) ~[HikariCP-2.7.9.jar!/:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.getConnection(HikariPool.java:148) ~[HikariCP-2.7.9.jar!/:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:128) ~[HikariCP-2.7.9.jar!/:na]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar!/:5.2.17.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.java:35) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar!/:5.2.17.Final]
        at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.acquireConnectionIfNeeded(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:106) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar!/:5.2.17.Final]
        at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.getPhysicalConnection(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:136) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar!/:5.2.17.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.connection(SessionImpl.java:524) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar!/:5.2.17.Final]
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor72.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:223) ~[spring-core-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:207) ~[spring-core-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect$HibernateConnectionHandle.doGetConnection(HibernateJpaDialect.java:391) ~[spring-orm-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.beginTransaction(HibernateJpaDialect.java:154) ~[spring-orm-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:400) ~[spring-orm-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:378) ~[spring-tx-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:474) ~[spring-tx-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:289) ~[spring-tx-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98) ~[spring-tx-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139) ~[spring-tx-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:135) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92) ~[spring-aop-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:61) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy98.findById(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at com.zf.trw.visualisation.shared.service.LineService.findById(LineService.java:537) ~[classes!/:20190213_1523]
        at com.zf.trw.visualisation.ui.controller.LineController.getLineStatus(LineController.java:65) ~[classes!/:20190213_1523]
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor102.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:209) ~[spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136) ~[spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:877) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:783) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:974) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:866) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar!/:8.5.32]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:851) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar!/:8.5.32]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar!/:8.5.32]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar!/:8.5.32]
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.32.jar!/:8.5.32]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar!/:8.5.32]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar!/:8.5.32]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:66) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357) ~[spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270) ~[spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar!/:8.5.32]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar!/:8.5.32]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar!/:8.5.32]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar!/:8.5.32]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar!/:8.5.32]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar!/:8.5.32]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar!/:8.5.32]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar!/:8.5.32]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar!/:8.5.32]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar!/:8.5.32]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar!/:8.5.32]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar!/:8.5.32]
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar!/:8.5.32]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar!/:8.5.32]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar!/:8.5.32]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar!/:8.5.32]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar!/:8.5.32]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:800) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar!/:8.5.32]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar!/:8.5.32]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:800) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar!/:8.5.32]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1471) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar!/:8.5.32]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar!/:8.5.32]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_201]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_201]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar!/:8.5.32]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_201
```

]

Further information. The settings I was applying to Hikari within my application.properties file were not being applied, hence why I was not seeing any errors relating to leaks being detected. I have fixed that problem and can see there is indeed a leak. The leak appears to originate from a controller, which calls a method on a service, which calls a method on a JpaResository. The problem is, I don't understand why this leak would be occuring.

The controller method is;

```
@RequestMapping("/{lineId}/product")
    @ResponseBody
    public String displayCurrentProductForline(@PathVariable("lineId") Long lineId) {
        Line line = lineService.findById(lineId);

        return line.getCurrentProductName() != null ? line.getCurrentProductName() : "Unknown Product";
    }
```

The method in the lineService is;

```
public Line findById(Long id) {
        Optional<Line> line = lineRepository.findById(id);

        return line.isPresent() ? line.get() : null;
    }
```

and finally, the repository;

```
@Repository
public interface LineRepository extends CrudRepository<Line, Long> {

    /**
     * Return a list of lines by their active value
     * @param active the active value
     * @return List of lines
     */
    public List<Line> getByActive(Boolean active);

}
```

As you an see, there isn't anything special going on here, we're just grabbing a Line from the database matched by it's Id, then the line is being passed to a view.

Another update, I've set the number of connections to 50, but when I run a query on the database to see the number of connections on the MSSQL database, it's only showing 4 connections instead of 50.

Comment: can you share you application.properties/yml on how you configure datasource?

Comment: can you also post the whole stacktrace for that error?

Comment: Sadly it's difficult to post the full stacktrace, the application is running on a remote machine that doesn't have internet access. So I have no way of easily getting that.

Answer (score 0):

Try change in both [dataSourceClassName](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP#popular-datasource-class-names) to recommended `com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource`

trwbi.datasource.driverClassName==com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource

> MS SQL Server  Microsoft   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource

Follow [Hibernate](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP#popular-datasource-class-names) recommendations for `provider_class` according to version

> As of Hibernate 4.3.6 there is an official ConnectionProvider class from Hibernate, which should be used instead of the HikariCP implementation. The class is called org.hibernate.hikaricp.internal.HikariCPConnectionProvider

Also you probably have a leak you can find using adding [leakDetectionThreshold](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP#popular-datasource-class-names) property

> This property controls the amount of time that a connection can be out of the pool before a message is logged indicating a possible connection leak. A value of 0 means leak detection is disabled. Lowest acceptable value for enabling leak detection is 2000 (2 seconds).

Comment: I've tried added the lead detection property with a value of 2000, but it didn't show any errors that indicated a leak, but I was still getting the timeout error. I've also tried to switch to using the drive you've put above, but I'm unable to find the correct POM to add to my project for it.

Comment: Yep, there is no warning before the exception, so does that mean there isn't a leak? I'm using Spring Data and JPA repositories, so I'm not opening or closing any resources, I'm leaving that to Spring. Also not sure of Hibernate version, it's whatever version is installed by Spring Boot 2.0.4

Comment: I've added further information to my original question.

Comment: @SheppardDigital did you add `spring.jpa.hibernate.connection.provider_class=org.hibernate.hikaricp.internal.HikariCPConnectionProvider`?

Comment: I think the problem was to do with an ajax request being made by the UI via javascript. If the application stopped running, I think javascript was pooling up requests until the system came back online, and then firing all requests at the system in one go when it came back online.

Comment: It turns out the UI wasn't the problem. I restarted the application yesterday, it's worked for 18 hours and now it's throwing up the same error again. Now every time I run it, within minutes it throws up this error. I don't understand how it can work for 18 hours, then stop, and won't work again even after a restart.

Comment: @SheppardDigital i am getting the same problem after deploying on google cloud....after some hours its throwing unable to acquire jdbc connection